# How to create YouTube video link in Tumblr?

Tags: youtube, tumblr, video, tumblr-themes

I would like to make my Tumblr page look like this website with YouTube video that can be turned on and off, [readyplayeronemovie.com](http://readyplayeronemovie.com)

So I don't know what theme do I have to use or how do I modify the theme's html to achieve that?

Comment: [customize a theme](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes)